# Redis scan command match option does not work in Python

Tags: python, redis

I use python redis to match some infomation by using match option? but it doesn't work.

```
 import redis
 import REDIS

 class UserCache(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.rds = self._connectRds() 

    def _connectRds(self):
        _db = REDIS['usercache']
        pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host=_db['HOST'], port= _db['PORT'], db=_db['DB'])
        rds = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool) 
        return rds 

 cache = UserCahce()
 cache.rds.execute("scan", "0", match="userinfo_*")
```

It seems that match option does work in scan command.

> In [68]: cache.rds.execute_command("scan", "0", match="userinfo_*")
>   Out[68]: 
>   ['28',
>    ['user_dev_20199116',
>     'devinfo_af85d776fcc9dbc56e3cca16594e1c9ec36fecd10000000001',
>     'devinfo_dd552211d1b97a825c416aaaf3c62ce8ce4661820000000002',
>     'user_dev_2',
>     'userinfo_20130243',
>     'session_r4XXdvzJ28VuPMoWWU4cnsNv7NEAAAAAAQ==',
>     'devinfo_35372afae1de3dbf6a213f659c2814c7b1767f2400013436cc',
>     'session_3IaTKySREBKjMTAi1puQSwzO20wAAAAAAQ==',
>     'session_3VUiEdG5eoJcQWqq88Ys6M5GYYIAAAAAAg==',
>     'user_dev_20130243']]

Comment: I scan the userinfo, check it by starting with "userinfo", and solve the problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the SCAN command like this :

```
r = Redis(....) #redis url
for user in r.scan_iter(match='userinfo_*'):
  print(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

hscan seems much quicker than scan, better use **hscan**, *only if you are sure about the key, if you need to search all keys then use* **scan**

```
for name in r.hscan_iter('live_AP_460000','name'):
   print(name) #for a single child key

for hash in r.hscan_iter('live_AP_460000'):
   print(hash) #for all child keys
```

**hscan is quicker than scan**, only if you are searching for a correct key, else to fetch all keys with some similar pattern, go for **scan**. For reference. [How to search a key pattern in redis hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850608/how-to-search-a-key-pattern-in-redis-hash)