# How to search a key pattern in redis hash?

Tags: python, redis

I have a hash table whose keys are of pattern USER_TEL like:

```
bob_123456  : Some address
mary_567894 : other address
john_123456 : third address
```

Now, I'd like to get addresses of all uses who have the same TEL in their keys.

What I came up with is:

```
tel = 123456
r.hmget('address_book', '*_%s' % tel)
```

I get `[None]` instead of the values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [HSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command.

For example:

```
redis> HMSET address_book bob_123456 Address1 mary_567894 Address2 john_123456 Address3
OK
redis> HSCAN address_book 0 match *_123456
1) "0"
2) 1) "bob_123456"
   2) "Address1"
   3) "john_123456"
   4) "Address3"
```

---

#### Update

Python implementation:

```
r = Redis(....) #redis url
for address in r.hscan_iter('address_book', match='*_123456'):
  print(address)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here is the python implementation that you may want to add to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30110574/4151875

Comment: Tried both scan and hscan, hscan seems quick than scan

Comment: is any option in Redis to scan directly with value? here Address1